# Codeigniter routing with forward slashes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Codeigniter routing rules don't seem to pick up anything after a slash for me - is this the default behaviour - how can I prevent it?

Example:

In routes.php:

```
$route['blog/read-post/(.+)'] = 'blog/lookup_blog_alias/$1';
```

In controller:

```
function lookup_blog_alias($str){
print $str;
}
```

If I enter a url such as:

```
http://localhost/blog/read-post/a-b-c/12
```

I only get the "a-b-c" part when what I would like is "a-b-c/12".

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by default, your requirement will only work if you change the route URL & the controller method to something like this:-

```
$route['blog/read-post/(.+)/(.+)'] = 'blog/lookup_blog_alias/$1/$2';

// Controller Method
function lookup_blog_alias($str1, $str2){
  print $str1.'/'.$str2;
}
```

You need to follow the basics of the CodeIgniter [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/), where it says that it's the convention of CI to mark a limit of string with the character "`/`" (forward-slash). It simply means that in between two forward-slashes, the following things can / may be considered in a general [MVC Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):-

- Module Name
- Controller (Class) Name
- Controller Method Name
- (1st) Query String's Index
- (1st) Query String's Value
- (2nd) Query String's Index
- (2nd) Query String's Value
- ... (Query String's Index / Value Pair)

However, in the "`routes.php`" page of CodeIgniter, the logic can be changed by the virtue of HTAccess. Still the above concept stands straight & so it will be wise to follow the normal MVC architecture.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. It's still annoying but at least I know why it's annoying now :)